# Continuing an analytic continuation of the Dirichlet $\eta$-function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

The [Dirichlet $\eta$-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html) is defined as:
$$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}  \qquad \Re(s) > 0$$

and has the full analytical continuation:

$$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} + \frac{(-1)^N}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}}{\cosh(\pi x)}\,dx \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}  \tag{1}$$

valid for all integers $N \ge  0$.

Wondered what would happen for negative $N$ and found numerically that:

$$\eta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{-N-1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} + (-1)^{s+1}\,\frac{(-1)^N}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}}{\cosh(\pi x)}\,dx\qquad s \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{2}$$

valid for all integers $N < 0$.

Note: assume the sums to be zero when their end values are $< 1$.

**Question:**

Is there a way to also expand equation (2) to $s \in \mathbb{C}$? If possible, I believe this would require some smart continuation of the $(-1)^{s+1}$ factor. Experimented with functions like $\cos\left(\pi(s+1)\right)$, but no success yet.

***ADDED:***

For the [Dirichlet $\beta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) the same phenomenon and question apply:

$$\beta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^s} + \frac{(-1)^N}{2^{s+1}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N +ix)^{-s}}{\cosh(\pi x)}\,dx \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}  \tag{3}$$

for all $N \ge 0$, except at $N=0$ the domain is reduced to $\Re(s) < 1$.

$$\beta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{-N} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^s} + (-1)^s\,\frac{(-1)^N}{2^{s+1}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N +ix)^{-s}}{\cosh(\pi x)}\,dx \qquad s \in \mathbb{Z}  \tag{4}$$

for all $N \lt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned making a precise answer but for a continuous branch of $(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}$,  $F_N(s)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}}{\cosh(\pi x)}\,dx$ converges and is analytic for $\Im(s)\in (a,b)$ where $a,b$ depend on your branch of $(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}$, you can easily switch two branches sending $F_N(s)$ to $F_N(s) e^{2i\pi k s}$, for the correct branch and $\Re(s)>1$ and the correct bound on $\Im(s)$ you can shrink the contour around the poles of $1/\cosh$ (the $\Im(x)>0$ or $\Im(x)<0$ poles depending on $sign(N)$, as we want to avoid the branch point of $(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}$) obtaining from the residue theorem a relation with $\eta(s)$ which extends by analytic continuation to $\Im(s)\in (a,b)$ and the $F_N$ obtained from other branches of $(N+1/2 +ix)^{-s}$.